# Problems with single target dps as fire wizard (d3)

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/wizard#aPNOSj!YiSe!cYYcZa

That's my build, and I completely decimate rifts on t5 until I come up to a yellow elite or rift boss.  My damage is seriously lacking against single targets, what skill should I change to fix that?

Also, I don't have a mirrorball.  If I do get one, will it help a lot against single targets? I heard mirrorball magic missile(fire) destroys single targets but not too sure how true that is.

Note: I have about 120% damage to fire, so I'm not sure that a non-fire skill is worth using.

Comment: Personally I'd switch Sparkflint Familiar for Arcane Orb with Scorch. Though I've also never really used Familiars so I don't know how useful they can be.

Comment: It's actually really nice damage for single target.  I attack 2 times per second, so the familiar does 358% wep damage per sec (plus the 120% dmg to fire and overall 10% damage to all my skills)

Comment: mirror ball is exactly what you need. Triple MM spam vs single targets with the conflag rune is one of the highest single target dps in the game.  What you heard is absolutely true.

Comment: I have been experimenting with massive cooldowns and mirror image with the 4x rune. Damage-wise it isn't great, but if you stagger mirror image with blackhole, you pretty much stun-lock whole mobs ffor about 70% of the time. throw in a solid freeze/cold ability [...]. Mirror image loves to spam black hole

Comment: In all honesty, if anything on T5 causes problems it just means that you need more gear and only more playing will solve that. If you are trying to focus your build I would suggest "shift+L" and checkout the leaderboard builds. But really, you probably just need more gear (SoJ) and those rare/elite packs will go down no problem! :)

Answer (score -1):

You have one quick option: change meteor rune from shower to molten impact. It does effectively much more damage while still maintaining solid AoE.

Since you have a black hole, there should not be a problem with your smaller AoE of meteor, you will pull mobs into one place where meteor will strike.

Your passive audacity just makes the molten impact more reasonable choice: you launch 2 meteors close to your character (remember, 15 yards is small, you can visualise by comparing Andariel's Visage poison dmg on hit which has ~15 yards AoE), while they fall you activate black hole, then spawn two more meteors. Recharge arcane, rinse and repeat.

Mirroball is ok, but I wouldn't bother obtaining it, it is much easier to stack lightning damage and go with electrocute forked lightning then.

Comment: Mirrorball/fire is waaaay better than any lightning builds right now for higher torment levels.

Comment: Not necessarily. Forked lightning still strikes a much larger area than MM. single targets are a different story on that one, and I completely agree.

the problem I see is everybody is reading forums and copying the same freaking build over and over again. Why not trying something else? Like battlemage wiz (almost melee range)? I am currently aspiring towards this option.

The gear diversity given by unique affixes on certain equipment really makes you want to try different things. :)

Comment: the problem is that builds naturally become optimized as you reach higher torment levels, its just the way the game is.  Either the game is so easy that not optimized builds can work at all levels or only optimized builds succeed at higher difficulty.  Can't have both unless all skills do variants of the same thing without much difference.  Even melee wiz is actually one of those 'cookie cutter' builds but requires either a wand of woh(fire) or moonlight ward(arcane).

Comment: The problem is molten impact adds a 15 second cooldown, and the only cdr I get is from paragon. And I do believe fire is better because of the extra +fire% from cinder, magefists and firebird's source (which I'm currently using)

Comment: Right, sorry, I completely forgot for the cooldown :(

I am myself playing arcane meteor build, it has reduced resource cost and deals massive damage when used correctly.